# How to add XML schema and XML element together in same file?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

[image]**

I want to add XML schema and XML element together in same file. Because this xml file we will need to generate through `C#` based on specific record. So, i am looking some code help how can i write together XMLSchema and  XML element in same file and inside same element. Please check attachment.

```
<Survey>
   **Here i want XML schema** 
   **Here i want XML element** 
</Survey>
```

Comment: *Because this xml file we will need to generate through C# based on specific record.* - then might you please explain what problem you have encountered that prevents you from doing that?  How are you trying to write the xsd and XML to a file?  How are you currently representing them in memory?  Can't you just write them using [`XmlWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: You are missing the schema tag : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp

Comment: It's done. @dbc Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Working Code Example

```
SiteSurveyX siteSurveyX = new SiteSurveyX();
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("c:\\temp\\TestSiteSchema.xsd");
//siteSurveyX.SurveySchema = XmlSchema.Read(reader, null);
XmlSchema myschema = XmlSchema.Read(reader, null);
string filePath = HelperFunctions.SurveyFilePath + routeName;
////Get all node record from DB
siteSurveyX.Survey = routeService.GetRouteDetailForXML(routeId, Convert.ToString(ddlRoute.Text), chkCurrentInterruption.Checked);

using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    lblStatus.Text = "Preparing file";
    stream.Close();
    stream.Dispose();

    //Convert record in XML
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SiteSurveyX));
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, siteSurveyX);
        lblStatus.Text = "Ready";
    }
}
```

It's done with this code.